Get .net release info in machine readable format
We are building .net components/tools for our customers. Some of the tools are not built for months (to optimize used built minutes on the cloud). Recently I was tasked with tracking if we are releasing tools with vulnerable .net versions for making the case for more frequent builds. I have access to build pipeline logs (Which date the SDK was downloaded and built) and source files (Which version of .net was targetted). I am looking for machine readable information for the following for each SDK:

.net SDK Version and Relase date
Contained runtime versions
Supported Visual Studio Versions
If this contains security patch

These information are readily available on web page
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0
I am hoping there is a machine readable (json) format that I can download and use.
